# Does the empty set have a minimum if it is a subset of R?

Tags: order-theory, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

True or False: As a subset of $\bf{R}$: $\emptyset$ has a minimum.

What is the difference between a supremum and the maximum? are they used interchangeably?

Comment: You probably mean "maximum," not "minimum."

Comment: Yes sorry I'm a little tired haha

Answer (score 3):

A maximum of a set $A$ is a supremum that is also an element of $A$. But a supremum of $A$ need not be in $A$ necessarily, so all maxima are suprema while not all suprema are maxima.

As an example, the set $[0,1)$ with the standard order on $\mathbb{R}$ has a supremum ($1$) but no maximum.

As for this particular question: it's rather trivial, since a maximum of $A$ is necessarily an element of $A$, but nothing is an element of the empty set.

Comment: Ok so the empty set would also not have a minimum, since I'm assuming the minimum is an element as well.

Comment: Also how about a lower bound and an infimum? are these also considered elements in sets?

Comment: Lower bounds and infima don't have to be elements of their respective sets. You should apply the definition of lower bound to the empty set to determine if it should have any lower bounds at all. (Or, you could think about the least upper bound property of the reals.)